# insert into a vector with iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have to insert elements on a specific position in a vector using iterator.
I can NOT use the insert() function (I have gotten clear guidelines that I'm supposed to do it without insert()).

this is my code (or at least the part that messes up):

```
cerr << "distance before resize: " << distance(wl.begin(), pos) << endl;
wl.resize(wl.size()+1);
cerr << "distance after resize: " << distance(wl.begin(), pos) << endl;
move_backward(pos, wl.end()-1, wl.end());
(*pos) = temp;
```

my output:

```
distance before resize: 0
distance after resize: -322
```

so apperantly, my resize messes up the iterator pos. Any ideas on how to fix this?

**edit:** You might wanna know how I declare my iterator:

```
auto pos = wl.begin();
```

Comment: `resize` will probably reallocate the internal memory of the `vector`. Your `pos` points somewhere in the middle of the original memory, which no longer exists. Instead, store the index of the position you want, and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resize *cannot* preserve the iterator since the resizing operation might invalidate the very content the iterator points to.

Stardard procedure would be to check if you need a resize first, and after the optional resizing operation you proceed with inserting new elements in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `std::vector::push_back` to insert the new element at the back, followed by [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) from `<algorithm>` to rotate the last element into the desired position.

Of course `push_back` does not preserve iterators, so use `std::distance(v.begin(), it)` first (from `<iterator>`) to determine the index of the desired position.

Comment: `std::rotate` is a clever solution, but you gave the OP a homework answer without making them think about it :(

Comment: @RickYorgason: Hm, maybe, but then again I don't get paid to make people think... :-S (They can go to school if they want that.)

Answer (score 0):

Resizing a vector invalidates its iterators. After the call to `resize()`, `pos` is not a valid iterator and should be reassigned to `wb.begin()` again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the intent of this exercise is to teach you about [iterator invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules), so the question you should be asking yourself is "Is there any equivalent to an iterator that *doesn't* get invalidated?"